# Deleted App on Bluemix yet name not available on recreate

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I deleted an app on Bluemix that was causing me some problems, basically to start over. However right after deleting when I try to recreate I get "The name is already used by another app."

How can I delete it completely and reuse the name?

I checked via the command line as well and "cf apps" does not list it. So the name is somehow still in use just not visible to me.

Comment: what is the app name and what Bluemix region you are using?

Comment: it was called "events". So the url for it was events.mybluemix.net
Region - US South

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When an app gets deleted, the route (and thus the URL) is not released yet.  The routes are reserved on a particular space, not on the organization level.  Are you sure you are using the same space as before?  If your app was installed on some other space before, you can go to that space and use the command

```
cf delete-route
```

to delete the unused route.  One thing that you can check if that route is owned by that space is to do a

```
cf routes
```

to see if that route belongs to the space that you are currently using.